# why do I get either a Socket Exception or the wrong data when I do a DNS lookup?

Tags: c#, .net, url, dns, ip-address

When I open firefox and enter "209.191.122.70" as the URL and press enter, it immediately resolves to "http://failsafe.fp.yahoo.com/404.html"

My goal is to retrieve the same information programmatically.

When I use the following code, either I end up with a SocketException or I end up with a HostName that doesn't look like the url I get when I use firefox.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostByAddress("209.191.122.70");
        Console.WriteLine(entry.HostName); //ir1.fp.vip.mud.yahoo.com
        Console.Read();
    }
```

The `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` I get when I try some other addresses says "The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found" and the stack trace looks as follows:

```
 at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByAddress(IPAddress address, Boolean includeIPv6, Boolean throwOnFailure)
 at System.Net.Dns.GetHostByAddress(String address)
 at reverseIP.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\test\Program.cs:line 15
```

Some of the addresses that give me exceptions resolve fine in firefox.

Other than starting Firefox as a separate process and retrieving the text in the address bar using the Windows API, how can I retrieve the information I'm looking for?

Comment: This is probably the result of a [Http Redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection).

Comment: This site has a poor reputation when trying to connect to an UnTrusted Site.. John what kind of Site is this you are trying to log into..? WOT has a big bright RED when trying to long onto this site even using https://209.191.122.70

Comment: Here are the Page Details when trying to access that IPAddress 
`The certificate is only valid for the following names:
  www.yahoo.com , yahoo.com , us.yahoo.com , kr.yahoo.com , uk.yahoo.com , ie.yahoo.com , fr.yahoo.com , in.yahoo.com , ca.yahoo.com , br.yahoo.com , de.yahoo.com , es.yahoo.com , mx.yahoo.com , it.yahoo.com , sg.yahoo.com , id.yahoo.com , ph.yahoo.com , qc.yahoo.com , tw.yahoo.com , hk.yahoo.com , cn.yahoo.com , au.yahoo.com , ar.yahoo.com , vn.yahoo.com  

(Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser class helped me obtain the info I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse-Lookup of an IP address is *not* what Firefox is doing here.

Firefox is simply issuing a http get to that IP.

In Pseudo code (because I lack access to a compiler at the moment) the equivalent of what Firefox is doing is

```
try {
 var request = WebClient.CreateRequest("http://209.191.122.70");
 request.GetResponse();
}
catch(WebException ex) {
 // handle 404 exception here.. You can access the response URL too.
}
```